# Rewrite URLs not in root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

This is what I have so far, its not working as I'd hoped:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1/ [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Basically I want to remove index.php everywhere, and in a directory I want to edit a query string also, like so:

```
https://example.com/directory/?id=Test
```

Should be:

```
https://example.com/directory/Test/
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the RewriteBase directive.

I've got it working here for you: https://mi-linux.wlv.ac.uk/~in9352/directory/5

Here's what I have in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /~in9352/directory/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?id=$1 [L]
```

Obviously you don't need the "~in9352"

Here's the documentation: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase